# Evaluate JavaScript in Sublime

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Does anyone know of a Sublime Text 3 package that exists that "live" evaluates my JavaScript code as I type it?

I tried the installing `EvalPrinter` package, however it does not work on Mac.

As an example, if my code is:

```
var x = 5 + 2;
```

Maybe it would show as:

```
var x = 5 + 2;      //x = 7
```

I thought I saw this somewhere once...
Displaying it in some other manner would also be ok.

Thanks.

Comment: https://pawelgrzybek.com/javascript-console-in-sublime-text/

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Javascript-Console-in-Sublime-Text

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Thanks!  The first link is a good start (only works if i add a `console.log` and has to be run manually each time, but pretty good overall).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's this https://quokkajs.com/

... and a few more characters so that stackoverflow allows this as an answer.